# How to add SharePoint Chrome Control to provider-hosted add-in based on MVC 5?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, mvc

I am writing a high-trust provider-hosted **SharePoint add-in** that is based on the built-in MVC 5 web template, and I need to add the **SharePoint Chrome control** so that the add-in fits with the overall look-and-feel of the host site collection. All of the examples I have found are based on the ASPX template. Are there any working examples of adding the SharePoint Chrome Control to an add-in that is based on **MVC 5** and not on ASPX?

Answer (score 0):

It should work in MVC 5 as well. Its quite similar to what we do in Web Forms implementation.

Just some minor differences. Instead of the aspx page, we will modify the layout html.

Open the Views > Shared folder.

In that modify the `_layouts.cshtml` file.

Add the below references of scripts in its `<head>` section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){        

    var spHostUrl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostUrl'));

    var layoutsRoot = spHostUrl + '/_layouts/15/';  

    $.getScript(layoutsRoot + 'SP.UI.Controls.js', renderSPChrome);

});


function getQueryStringParameter(urlParameterKey) {
    var params = document.URL.split('?')[1].split('&');
    var strParams = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
        var singleParam = params[i].split('=');
        if (singleParam[0] == urlParameterKey)
            return singleParam[1];
    }
}

function renderSPChrome() {

    var hostlogourl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter('SPHostLogoUrl'));

    var options = {
        'appIconUrl': hostlogourl,
        'appTitle': @ViewBag.Title,        
        'settingsLinks': [
            {
                'linkUrl': 'https://sitecollectionUrl.com',
                'displayName': 'Site Collection Name'
            }
        ]
    };

    //Load the Chrome Control into chromeCtrlPlaceholder div 
    var chromeNavigation = new SP.UI.Controls.Navigation('chromeCtrlPlaceholder', options);
    chromeNavigation.setVisible(true);
}

</script>
```

Add the below div in the `<body>` section.

`<div id="chromeCtrlPlaceholder"></div>`

It will load the SP Chrome control

Comment: I used similar code, but found that it fails in the high-trust scenario, depending on how the PHA is setup to handle SSL.  I keep getting protocol errors when it tries to load the sp.ui.controls.js file.

Comment: Thats quite strange, can you directly add the CDN reference `https://microsoft.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/SP.UI.Controls.js` and check ?